# include a template and display its content in a popup in prestashop?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am new to prestashop.i am trying to include a template named "shopping-cart.tpl" in footer.tpl.

```
  <div id="step2" class="pannel">
{include file="$tpl_dir./shopping-cart.tpl"}
</div>
```

I need to display its content in a popup on all pages.But it is not working except for index.php?controller=order-opc page